# как перевести [ if a<4 and a>2 ] на lua

Tags: python, lua

мне для одной програмы надо чтобы действие происходило с 100 до 200

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я писал скрипты на Скриптовой API для SAMP, может знаете о чём я, так вот там синтаксис был таков:

```
if a < 4 and a > 2 then
    --code
elseif a > 4 and a < 2 then
    --code
else
    --code
end
```

`else` и `elseif` добавлять не обязательно, просто показал как пример.

Comment: Что в нём интересного?

Comment: в нем грамматическая ошибка скорее всего. Вряд ли там должно быть then между 4 и and. Ну и как вы себе представляете ситуацию, что ``а`` одновременно больше 4 и меньше 2?

Comment: А да, then лишнее, я не заметил